# Running simpleaudio in python

Tags: python

I successfully installed simpleaudio using "sudo pip3 install simpleaudio"

When I try to use it starting with 'import simpleaudio as sa'
I get an error message 'ImportError: No module named simpleaudio'

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed simpleaudio with pip3, it should be available for use with Python3, maybe your default Python installation is Python2. You can check the current running version of Python with:

```
python --version
```

If that's the case, you can run Python3 with:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

If want to use Python3 as default, create an alias on your bashrc:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

And source your bash:

```
source .bashrc
```

Comment: I'm now running my code in Python3.  I get the following error.  ImportError: cannot import name 'simpleaudio'

Comment: Can you run `which -a python`? If there's a python installation on your /usr/local/bin try to run with `/usr/local/bin/python` and then `import simpleaudio`

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my code.  simpleaudio now runs.  I'm using it because it says that it runs asynchronously.  I'm not seeing that.  any suggestions?

Comment: Simpleaudio is meant to run audio playbacks asynchronously by default, are you trying to run other operations after the audio has started?

Comment: Sorry, another S/W error.  Everything works as expected. Thank you very much,